# Can't install docker on Debian 8 Jessie anymore

Tags: docker, debian-jessie

I installed docker on Debian 8 Jessie before, following this instruction:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo debian-jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

But starting from 31.03.2020 the repositories in apt.dockerproject.org are deprecated and I can't install docker from there anymore.

How can I install docker on Debian 8 Jessie now, since I've failed to do it from download.docker.com?

Answer (score 3):

The [Debian 8 "Jessie"](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/) has been discontinued as of June 2018 and the LTS will end in June 2020. Despite there seems to be a Docker release for Jessie on https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/jessie/ it's last updated back in Jun 2019. **You should be upgrading your system** to a supported Debian 9 Stretch (oldstable) or Debian 10 Buster (stable), and then follow the instructions on [Install Docker Engine on Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/).

That said, it seems this release is signed with the same signing keys (the key `7EA0A9C3F273FCD8` is a subkey of `Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>` with ID `8D81803C0EBFCD88`), so you should be able to use the same instructions for using the unsupported version still available on the server:

- [Install using the repository](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-using-the-repository)
- [Install from a package](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/#install-from-a-package).

Comment: thanks for answer. So is it impossible to install docker without the Debian 8 upgrade?

Comment: Which part of the "*you should be able to use the same instructions*" was unclear to you? It might not be impossible, but it's certainly not recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

If despite the warnings of Debian Jessie being discontinued you still want to install Docker on it, try:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y sudo curl
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sh get-docker.sh
```

Comment: No longer works. Prints `DEPRECATION WARNING:  This Linux distribution (debian jessie) reached end-of-life and is no longer supported by this script. No updates or security fixes will be released for this distribution, and users are recommended to upgrade to a currently maintained version of debian.` when run. Install fails even after waiting a while.